# В чем разница между объявлением в файлах .h и .m?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Доброе время суток всем форумчанинам, обьясните пожалуйста разницу для тупореза, читал книги и никак не могу понять в чём собственно разница при обьявлении в файле .h и файле .m:

```
ViewController.h    
@interface NPViewControllersFactory : NSObject {
     NSString *string;
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *userInfoView;
@end

ViewController.m
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController() {
    NSString *string;
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *userInfoView;
@end

@implementation ViewController
...
@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В h файле описывают публичный интерфейс. В m файле описывают имплементацию (реализацию) и как в вашем случае приватный интерфейс (расширение).
То есть, если описать проперти в расширении (@interface ClassName() в m файле), то оно не будет доступно из вне. Если описать в h файле - доступ будет.

Comment: немного дополню - строго говоря вы таки сможете добраться до свойст и методов из расширения если где-нибудь объявите такую же категорию и будете с ней работать. Без этого собственно тоже сработает, но будет ругаться на то что метода может и не быть

Comment: То есть грубо говоря разница только в приватности?

Comment: Грубо говоря да. Почитайте про расширения (Objective-C Class Extension) и категории (Objective-C Category). Уверен, вы откроете для себя много интересного.

Comment: Обьясните ещё такой момент пожалуйста, какая разница портретирования классов/файлов в .h .m файле?